# Python-Magic ; Unable to find libmagic

Tags: python, dll, python-magic

I've downloaded and installed python-magic using "pip install python-magic".
Source: https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic

It downloaded and installed perfectly fine. I've also copied the 3 files (cygmagic-1.dll, cygwin1.dll, and cygz.dll) from cygwin installation into C:\Windows\System32.

Then, I also downloaded magic1.dll and placed it in System32 folder too.

But the command prompt is still giving me this error:

ImportError: failed to find libmagic.  Check your installation

Why is this so?

EDIT: I've included C:\cygwin\bin into PATH also.

Comment: @QuestionC because that thread doesn't answer my problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I just have to restart the computer for it to work. But ultimately, I still have problems using python-magic because of the "32bit" and "64bit" incompatibility bug. I guess I'll just check the file type by checking the extensions. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you also included

> C:\cygwin\bin

in your system path. That seems to be the step missing.

Comment: Oh forget to add in, yeah I've also included C:\cygwin\bin into the path already.. do you have any idea why?