# Python-magic has OSError: [WinError 193] error while running in 32-bit version of IDLE

Tags: python, python-magic

I have been trying to install the module [python-magic](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic) for a few hours, and I've been encountering some problems. I am using the 32-bit version of Python 3.5.2 with 64-bit Windows 7.

First, I used the command "`pip install python-magic`". I downloaded magic1.dll, regex2.dll, and zlib1.dll, and magic from the Files for Windows project, and I copied those four files to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\python_magic-0.4.12-py3.5.egg-info.
```

I added the aforementioned directory to the beginning of PATH in my Windows environment variables. Then I opened IDLE's Shell and typed "`import magic`" and got the response `OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found`.

I read that the "magic" file should have the extension .dll, so I renamed it. This led to the pop-up warning by Windows `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\magic.dll is either not designed to run on Windows or contains an error"` and by Python, `"OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application`". I read that the latter error is commonly encountered while running it in a 64-bit environment, but I made sure to run it in 32-bit IDLE and only have the 32-bit version of Python installed.

Following the advice of [previous StackOverflow posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816887/python-magic-unable-to-find-libmagic), I tried copying cygmagic-1.dll, cygwin1.dll, and cygz.dll to C:\Windows\System32, to the same folder as magic.dll, and I also tried renaming cygmagic-1.dll as magic1.dll, but that didn't have any effect. I know other places say you're not supposed to mix Cygwin Python and Windows Python, but I tried it without the involvement of these files, and it didn't work then, either.

I tried renaming magic.dll to magic.exe, and that allowed "import magic" and magic.`Magic(magic_file=r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\python_magic-0.4.12-py3.5.egg-info\magic.exe') with the response "<magic.Magic object at 0x02EA0A70>". When I tried testing with magic.from_file(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\README.txt'), though, I got the error magic.MagicException: b'could not find any magic files!` I figured that renaming it to magic.exe had to be wrong, but that it was worth a try.

After I gave up on python-magic, someone recommended an [older project](https://github.com/fallgesetz/pymagic). I downloaded it and put the pymagic folder in my site-packages directory. When I tried to import pymagic.pymagic, it told me that the module StringIO doesn't exist, and the recommender told me it was because StringIO is from Python2. I changed all mentions of StringIO to io and tried the command `pymagic.pymagic.identify_file(r'E:\Pictures\picture.jpg')`

This generated the error `TypeError: startswith first arg must be bytes or a tuple of bytes, not str.` I'm not involved enough with Python's os, io, etc. modules to know how to make modifications to get this to work. Can anyone make any recommendations on how to get python-magic or pymagic working, or any other module for identifying a file based on its header? I know this question has been asked a lot, but the previous answers didn't work out for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you call the 'magic' data file `magic`, and leave it in the same folder as `magic1.dll`?

Following your instructions I was able to reproduce the same error as you.  Using [Sysinternals Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx), I could see that the reason for your first error appeared to be that Python was trying to load the the magic data file as if it were the library.

I then renamed the magic data file to `magic_data`, restarted IDLE, and it worked. I  could then use `magic` to identify a file:

```
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:43:06) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import magic
>>> fn = r'C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\python_magic-0.4.12-py3.4.egg-info\magic_data'
>>> m = magic.Magic(magic_file=fn)
>>> m.from_file(r'C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\python_magic-0.4.12-py3.4.egg-info\zlib1.dll')
'PE32 executable for MS Windows (DLL) (console) Intel 80386 32-bit'
```

(I'm using a different version of Python (3.4), and a different version of Windows (10) to you, but I don't think these matter too much.)

Comment: That worked perfectly. As an aside, I encountered the 'WindowsError: exception: access violation writing 0x00000000 ' bug that the GitHub documentation warns about and resolved it by removing C:\cygwin\bin from my PATH.